# How to resolve "we're having trouble determining your PC Windows Consumer Preview"?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I have been trying to install windows 8 consumer preview on my PC. I created a bootable Windows 8 flash drive using Windows 7 USB tool(downloaded from internet). When i click the setup icon, i recieve the following error:
**Something Happened.**
****Sorry, we're having trouble determining your PC Windows Consumer Preview. Please close setup and try again.****

What is wrong with it? I have downloaded Windows 8 ISO file from Microsoft website.
I also tried to boot through USB but my pc doesn't support it.
My PC also fulfills the recommended requirements. Currently I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and had to do two things to get my USB flash drive installation to work:

1. Boot into Windows 7.  Instead of running autorun or \setup.exe, run \sources\setup.exe.  This gets around the "Something happened" issue you are seeing.
2. That got me further, but I got a dreaded meaningless error: "an error prevented a required compliance check from completing".  All I did was go to the Windows 7 Disk Management (Right-click Computer, click Manage, then find Disk Management), and make sure my existing windows partition (that I am upgrading) is marked active.  I right click it and click "Mark Partition as Active".  (It may also need to be a Primary partition and marked as Boot, but that was already the case for me.)

(*My setup*: my USB stick was created by Apple's Bootcamp assistant using x64 Windows Consumer Preview, for my triple-boot Macbook Air that boots using EFI loader and then Grub for Win/Linux.)

---

Also, I don't know why I can't comment on the other answer, regarding corruption, but Microsoft provides the SHA 1 hases for the iso images right on [the download page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/download).  (I used the convenient Windows Explorer properties window extension called [Summer Properties](http://www.frozenlogic.org/windows.shtml) to verify the hash.)  (Oh, I just discovered I can't comment because I am riffraff who just walked in off the street: 50 reputation needed.)

Comment: Marking the partition as active did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Marking the partition as active worked for me as well, thanks!

Comment: `Mark partition as active` is grayed out :( ... ? seems EUFI mode and diskpart doesnt allow "marking as active"

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes when your file is corrupted or not download completely. Please re-download it. If you are using IDM and your computer restarts or if you stop your download, then it usually stops the download. You could try [Bittorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/) to alleviate that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just *uninstall*(not just disable) any anti-virus program you are running either by downloading the uninstaller utility from the respective anti-virus's website or from the Windows add or remove program (the former method is recommended).

Restart your computer and try to install Windows now, it should be fine OR 
just go into the `Sources` folder in the windows installation disk/drive and run `Setup.exe`.